# Traduction de « not on my watch »

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

*Not on my watch !* est une expression idiomatique anglaise. Quelle en serait la traduction la plus exacte en Français ? On me suggère *moi vivant, jamais !*, qui est proche, mais avec une nuance un peu plus violente et chaotique (ça correspondrait à *over my dead body*). Peut-on faire mieux ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Watch* c'est le tour de garde (du soldat par exemple) donc *Moi vivant, jamais* est effectivement beaucoup trop fort.
*Pas de ça avec moi*, comme le propose M'vy convient. Si on veut garder de façon plus soutenue l'idée de responsabilité impliquée par l'expression anglaise on pourrait dire *Pas tant que je serai en charge* ou *Pas tant que je suis responsable*.

Comment: Ou même «Pas de ça *chez* moi».

Answer (score 12):

Je vais le remettre ici alors, je propose :

> Pas de cela avec moi!

Comment: (+1) mais également, plus courant : *pas de ça avec moi!*

Answer (score 2):

Une alternative serait ***pas si je peux l'empêcher !***

Answer (score 0):

*Pas sous ma gouverne* serait correct.

Comment: Je ne connais pas cette expression, et [elle n'a pas été utilisée sur la toile](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22pas+sous+ma+gouverne%22) à part comme titre d'un livre où elle n'a pas exactement ce sens. Le mot [gouverne](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gouverne) n'a pas le même sens que *watch*, au moins en France (même si il peut aussi s'appliquer dans le cas où le locuteur est en position de pouvoir). Donc jusqu'à preuve du contraire je soutiens que « pas sous ma gouverne » n'est pas une traduction correcte.

Comment: Moi ça ne me choque pas. Ça fait peut-être un peu vieux jeu mais ce n'est pas du tout dérangeant.

Answer (score -7):

"Pas sur ma montre" pourrait fonctionner aussi

Comment: Uniquement chez [Chiflet](http://www.amazon.fr/husband-integrale-Ciel-mari-Lint%C3%A9grale/dp/2757810987) et ses imitateurs.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Même si les traductions littérale de ce type m’amusent, le but est tout de même de faire avancer le schmilblick. Un étudiant qui tomberait sur cette réponse pourrait même la prendre au premier degré.